# Creating categories and sub-categories in Magento Extension

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, categories

I am new to Magento Extension Development and wondering which is the best way to create categories and sub-categories from within an extension. The Extension I am working on is synchronizing product-data from an ERP-System. The extension is operating with a System->Configuration Dialog which holds the data for the connection to the server (user/pwd/etc.) Now I am wondering, if it is better to connect via Ajax request or use a Soap call. Ajax seems very slow in this case for about 700 Products. So what do you suggest?

Furthermore, I am a little stuck by creating categories and sub-categories. Is there simple way to do that. I found some stuff on creating a category and then use the ->move() function. Moreover I am wondering if the 'path' of the category is essential on creating sub-categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static function addCatalogCategory($item, $id, $storeId = 0) {
    /*
     * resource for checking category exists
     * http://fishpig.co.uk/blog/load-a-category-or-product-by-an-attribute.html
     */
    $categories = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection');
    // Select which fields to load into the category
    // * will load all fields but it is possible to pass an array of
    // select fields to load
    $categories->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    // Ensure the category is active
    $categories->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1);
    // Add Name filter
    $categories->addAttributeToFilter('name', $item->GROUP_NAME);
    // Limit the collection to 1 result
    $categories->setCurPage(1)->setPageSize(1);
    // Load the collection
    $categories->load();

    if ($categories->getFirstItem()->getId()) {
        $category = $categories->getFirstItem();
        return $category->getId();
    }

    /* get category object model */
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
    $category->setStoreId($storeId);
    $data = array();
    /* if the node is root */
    if (Heliumv_Synchronization_Helper_Data::xml_attribute($item, 'type') == 'root') {
        $data['category']['parent'] = 2; // 2 top level id
    } else {
        /* is node/leaf */
        $data['category']['parent'] = $id;
    }

    $data['general']['path'] = $item->PARENT_ID;
    $data['general']['name'] = $item->GROUP_NAME;
    $data['general']['meta_title'] = "";
    $data['general']['meta_description'] = "";
    $data['general']['is_active'] = "1";
    $data['general']['url_key'] = "";
    $data['general']['display_mode'] = "PRODUCTS";
    $data['general']['is_anchor'] = 0;

    /* add data to category model */
    $category->addData($data['general']);

    if (!$category->getId()) {
        $parentId = $data['category']['parent'];
        if (!$parentId) {
            if ($storeId) {
                $parentId = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getRootCategoryId();
            } else {
                $parentId = Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::TREE_ROOT_ID;
            }
        }
        $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId);
        $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());
    }

    $category->setAttributeSetId($category->getDefaultAttributeSetId());

    try {
        $category->save();

        return $category->getId();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo Mage::log($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone. cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should use magento models:

Create category with subcategory:

```
/**
 * After installation system has two categories: root one with ID:1 and Default category with ID:2
 */
/** @var $category1 Mage_Catalog_Model_Category */
$category1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$category1->setName('Category 1')
    ->setParentId(2)
    ->setLevel(2)
    ->setAvailableSortBy('name')
    ->setDefaultSortBy('name')
    ->setIsActive(true)
    ->setPosition(1)
    ->save();

/** @var $category2 Mage_Catalog_Model_Category */
$category2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$category2->setName('Category 1.1')
    ->setParentId($category1->getId()) // set parent category which was created above
    ->setLevel(3)
    ->setAvailableSortBy('name')
    ->setDefaultSortBy('name')
    ->setIsActive(true)
    ->setIsAnchor(true)
    ->setPosition(1)
    ->save();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is actually helpful. What about checking if the category already exists? Do you have any tips on this? Currently I am using the getTreeModel() Method to read all the ids/names.

Comment: one more thing, I assume the path is set automatically when the ParentId() is passed?

Comment: Path will be set in Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category::_afterSave()

Comment: To check whether category exists: `$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category'); $category->load($name, 'name'); if ($category->getId()) { // category exists }`

Comment: Sorry but this does not work at all. I managed to create all the categories using the following code: see Answer.